# access AJAX API using R

Tags: jquery, r, ajax

I'd like to access data from an jQuery/AJAX api within R.  Is there a way to call jQueries in R?

These are some examples of AJAX requests, would be great if I could translate them into R code and get the response back into a data frame.

```
$.ajax("https://nestiolistings.com/api/v2/agents/?key=<your_key>")
```

Or a more complex one,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://nestiolistings.com/api/v2/listings/350889/contact/?key=<your_api_key>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        email: 'johndoe@example.com',
        phone: '(212)576-5847',
        message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu has labores adipiscing id.'
    },
    contentType: 'application/json'
})
```

Link to their API docs:
http://developers.nestio.com/api/v2/listings.html#listing-contact

I also found this but it'd be great if I can get an example on how would this calls work on this specific API, and maybe there are other suggestions for jQuery packages within R.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html

Comment: You can do a post request using `httr::POST`.

Comment: does the API require any headers, or can you just use `httr::GET("https://nestiolistings.com/api/v2/agents/?key=<your_key>")` ?

Comment: and Selenium will surely be overkill for just querying an API

Comment: @SymbolixAU it doesn't require headers as far as I know, but I may be wrong.  For some odd reason I get a 403 error when trying...

Comment: 403 is a 'forbidden' error, correct? Are you sure your key is valid? Also worth trying `POST` : `httr::POST("https://nestiolistings.com/api/v2/agents/?key=<yo‌​ur_key>")`